# Work/Education/Training Information

Tags: f1-visas

I have an issue filling out the question, " Have you attended any educational institutions at a secondary level or above?", the university that I've been taking classes from is located in the USA, however the classes I've been taking are completely online, therefore I've never been in the USA taking classes in person from this school, how can I indicate this in the DS-160? Should I put the address of the school or leave that part empty?

Comment: Put the address. They care about the school, not where you took the lessons

Answer (score 9):

In these online days "attended" an educational institution means "taken classes" not "been physically present at".

Yes you have attended an educational institution. Put the address of the university (they need it so they can check you really did attend, not so they know where you were). It's probably worth noting somewhere in the application that the education was entirely online, just so they don't go looking for your visa records for when you took the classes.